# Trouble with fine tuning my neural network for digit recognition with SGD. I can't seem to get better than 87% on the test data

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, mnist

I can reliably get around 87% accuracy on my test data of 10,000 MNIST images, and about 98% accuracy on my training data. I developed the neural net from scratch alongside the development of a Matrix class to go along with it. Currently, I am using mini-batch stochastic gradient descent (mini batch of size 64) with a learning rate of 0.6. I am using a fixed learning rate which I heard is bad but I am a bit unsure of how best to incorporate a changing learning rate. This is an input -> hidden -> output layered MLP NN.

Currently, 5000 iterations are enough to get me around 70% accuracy (it also takes about 6 seconds) but if I want anything better, I have to iterate for 400k or so. I am keeping track of the average error of my output and graphing it on excel for every parameter change, and it always follows the model of dropping incredibly fast at first and then plateauing and having changes occur at MUCH larger intervals.

I want to implement momentum and a changing learning rate, but I am unfortunately a bit rusty with the notation of the math for backpropagation. I have looked at 20+ answers about implementing momentum but they all use the notation to describe it which would be fine if I understood it 100%. I get the idea behind using the past weight matrix to update the current, but my confusion comes into play when I am looking at where I would implement it in my specific code.

Here is the code for my forward and backpropagation, I would love any pointers about implementing momentum or a changing learning rate (or any suggestions at all about how to better improve my NN given the information I have provided). All the variables in forward prop are matricies (obvious but I just want to be clear)

```
    /**
     * forward propagate through the network
     */
    private void forwardPropagation(Matrix inputBatch, Matrix outputBatch, boolean training) {

        hiddenActivation = inputBatch.mult(inputToHiddenWeights);

        hiddenActivation = hiddenActivation.sigmoidify();

        outputActivation = hiddenActivation.mult(this.hiddenToOutputWeights);

        outputActivation = outputActivation.sigmoidify();

        if(training) {
            backPropagation(inputBatch, outputBatch);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Perform backpropagation algorithm to update the weights
     * and train the NN.
     */
    private void backPropagation(Matrix inputBatch, Matrix outputBatch) {

        // Compute gradient at output layer
        outputErrorMatrix = outputBatch.sub(outputActivation);

        // to keep track of the average error on every iteration (the data I plot)
        this.avgErrorPerIteration[iterationToEpsilon] = outputErrorMatrix.averageValue();

        // if the current error is less than a certain given error, exit and save weights
        if(this.avgErrorPerIteration[iterationToEpsilon] < this.epsilon) {
            this.lessThanEpsilon = true;
            return;
        }

        // to print out the initial error value (I compare it to the end value)
        if(iterationToEpsilon==0) {         
            System.out.println("Average error after first propagation: " + outputErrorMatrix.averageValue());
        }

        // compute slope at output and hidden layers
        Matrix slopeOutput = outputActivation.sigmoidifyPrime();
        Matrix slopeHiddenLayer = hiddenActivation.sigmoidifyPrime();

        // compute delta at output layer
        Matrix deltaOutput = (outputErrorMatrix.multAcross(slopeOutput)).mult(LEARNING_RATE);

        // calculate error at hidden layer
        Matrix hiddenError = deltaOutput.mult(hiddenToOutputWeights.transpose());

        // compute delta at hidden layer
        Matrix deltaHidden = hiddenError.multAcross(slopeHiddenLayer);

        // update weight at both output and hidden layers
        hiddenToOutputWeights = hiddenToOutputWeights.add(((hiddenActivation.transpose()).mult(deltaOutput)).mult(LEARNING_RATE));      
        inputToHiddenWeights = inputToHiddenWeights.add(((inputBatch.transpose()).mult(deltaHidden)).mult(LEARNING_RATE));

        iterationToEpsilon++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think momentum or changing the learning rate will help you have a better test accuracy, as these two techniques only help the optmization algorithm and your optimization algorithm is already doing quite well (as it is only tries to reduce the error on the training set, and this error is very low).

Apparently your neural network is overfitting the training set, so one thing you can try is [Dropout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropout_(neural_networks)). An easier thing you can try is [Weight decay](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part3/section-6.html). The point is, you need to regularize your network, as you are overfitting, and these two are regularization techniques, while the other two typically aren't.